# problems installing rails in arm system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, arm

I am trying to install RoR on a synology diskstation.

`uname -a`

Linux Sonne 2.6.32.12 #1922 Sun Sep 4 02:10:58 CST 2011 armv5tel GNU/Linux

ruby and rubygems is installed via ipkg

`ruby -v`

ruby 1.9.1p243 (2009-07-16 revision 24175) [arm-linux-eabi]

`gem -v`

1.8.11

dev-tools are installed. when I try to run `sudo gem install rails` I get an error when the json native extension is build:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /opt/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for re.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/opt/bin/ruby
/opt/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:362:in `try_do': The complier failed to generate an   executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
from /opt/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:431:in `try_cpp'
from /opt/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:809:in `block in have_header'
from /opt/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:668:in `block in checking_for'
from /opt/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:274:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
from /opt/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:248:in `open'
from /opt/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:274:in `block in postpone'
from /opt/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:248:in `open'
from /opt/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:270:in `postpone'
from /opt/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:667:in `checking_for'
from /opt/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:808:in `have_header'
from extconf.rb:14:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /opt/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.6.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /opt/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.6.1/ext/json/ext/parser/gem_make.out
```

As far as I can tell all necessary headers are there. What am I missing?

Comment: Hmm. Tried installing Rails on Ruby 1.9.2 on an Arch Arm Linux machine I have, worked fine, only minimal similarity in setup likely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use ruby 1.9.1 with rails, as stated in RoR website:

> We recommend Ruby 1.8.7 or Ruby 1.9.2 for use with Rails. Ruby 1.8.6
>   and earlier are not supported, neither is version 1.9.1.

Comment: hmm true...I'll try to build ruby 1.9.2